# How to finds the greatest number

Tags: arrays

How to compute the greatest number and display it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GreatestNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int [] num = new int [10];
int counter;
int max = 0;

Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
```

//Prompt user to enter numbers

```
for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++)
  {
   System.out.print("Enter StaffID to be edited:");
   num[i]=read.nextInt();
  }
```

//Compute the greatest number up to this point

//Display the greatest number

```
}//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i=0; i < num.length ; i++) 
    if (num[i] > maxVal) maxVal = num[i];

System.out.println(maxVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a number to the array, just check if it is greater than the current largest number, and if it is, then set max to the new number. This saves time looping through the array later to find out which number is the largest.

```
for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter StaffID to be edited:");
    num[i]=read.nextInt();
    if (num[i] > max)
    {
        max = num[i];
    }
}
```